# Basic Jquery Slider Modifications

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I just downloaded the Basic Jquery Slider, and the problem is I would like to modify it to the following specs:
1, images would be iPhones.
2, instead of displaying 1 image slider will display 3 images with the two outer images faded outward gradient.
3, when you click on the faded iPhone it will slide and center it in the slider.
The problem is though I don't know what to change, I can change images that's fine but how do I achieve the 3 picture gradient effect? 
Thanks for your efforts looking into this.
Alex

Comment: You need to generate the thumbs for the images. There are plenty of other scripts out there that do this without having to spend time modding a basic slider. But if you like the modding aspect you could try adapting this one: http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2

Comment: Also I have been trying to find the scripts but maybe I am not searching for the right one :/ that's why I'm asking here now to get an idea of how one would achieve this using a jquery slider.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/index.html lightbox is definitely the best way.

Comment: Sorry Vincent what do you mean lightbox I couldn't find anything saying lightbox. Maybe I missed it

Comment: It was on the parent page, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work instead: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/frogjs/index.htm

Comment: That might work is there much difference since it doesn't rely on js

Comment: This uses js for the transitions and animations. It still works without it however. The difference is minimal - won't affect the desired functionality.